# How do I use wine's new multi-channel audio support?

Tags: linux, audio, wine, alsa

Wine supposedly added [Multi-channel support to the ALSA driver](http://www.winehq.org/announce/1.5.11) in a recent release.  However, I haven't found any documentation about it or any reports of anyone successfully using it.  I have 5.1 surround sound through ALSA (not Pulse) on my linux system, yet games in wine don't seem to use anything more than stereo, no matter which ALSA device I select in winecfg.

Can someone explain what must be done to get wine games to use all my speakers for positional audio, or failing that, point me toward some useful documentation on the new multi-channel support?